# Firebase Admin NodeJS SDK - admin.messaging().send(msg) timing out for invalid FCM tokens

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

I have an AWS lambda backend with Firebase Admin Node SDK.

I'm using `admin.messaging().send(msg)` to send a FCM message. This is working well when both sender and receiver flutter apps installed correctly.

However when i delete the receivers app and then try to send the message, `admin.messaging().send(msg)` hangs indefinitely with no errors until lambda timeout after 30 sec.

```
export async function sendEnquiryMessage(messagingEvent: MessagingEvent, fcmToken: string) {

    let content = {
        title: `new Message from ABC`,
        body: `'${messagingEvent.message?.text ?? ""}' `,
    };

    console.log("sending a message to FCM: ", fcmToken);
    const message = {
        notification: {
            body: content.body,
            title: content.title,
        },
        data: {
            clickaction: 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK',
            id: '1',
            status: 'done',
            messagingEvent: JSON.stringify(messagingEvent),
        },
        apns: {
            payload: {
                aps: {
                    'mutable-content': 1,
                    'content-available': 1
                }
            }
        },
        token: fcmToken,
    };
    console.log("MESSAGE TO SEND: ", JSON.stringify(message));
    try {
       const messageId = await admin.messaging().send(message);
        console.log("MESSAGE SENT messageId ID was : ", messageId);
    } catch (e) {
        console.error('Error FCM message:', e);
    }
    return true;
}
```

I expected this to throw some kind of error if the receiver token is not valid or got deleted after uninstalling the app. I have a try catch, but its not catching any errors.Has anyone experienced this and how to fix it?

I installed the app again and signed in as the receiver, the same code started working again. So I suspect its related to the FCM token got invalidated during removal of the app and it causing the timeout during send().

Answer (score 0):

this turn out to be an error after catching the exception on,
 `console.error('Error FCM message:', e);`

after changing this `e` to `e.toString()`, code handles the error gracefully.

Someone please explain me why plain `e` would not work.